# Why does $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{x=3}^n{\frac{n!}{(n-x)!}}}{n!}\text{ as }n\to\infty$ give euler's number?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

TL; DR
While wondering how many permutations are there to fit *n* characters in 3+4+5+6+...+x character words (Like in the game [Word Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRZL9.png)), dividing by *n!* give *e*

This:

$$\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{x=3}^n{\frac{n!}{(n-x)!}}}}{n!}\text{ as }n\to\infty$$

Gives *e* (*2.718281828*) somehow.


Here is the full story:
I was playing [Word Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRZL9.png) (I suggest looking at the image for better understanding of the game)
and while programming a bot that would play the game for me, 
I was wondering how many possible permutations are there for *n* characters
that need to fit inside words with 3-*x* characters (depends on the word, as shown in the picture).
At first, my friend came up with this (wrong) formula (trust me its relevant):

## $\displaystyle\sum_{x=3}^n{n!}$

I Later found out this formula (right):

## $\displaystyle\sum_{x=3}^n{\frac{n!}{(n-x)!}}$

Explanation of the formula:

> Let's say I have 5 characters say a,b,c,d,e , how many possible ways are there to fit them
>  in a 2 character word?
>  (or, how many 2 character words are possible using the characters a,b,c,d,e)
>  The answer is 
>  $\frac{5!}{(5-2)!}$ 
>  Now, how many possible words are there using a,b,c,d,e that fit in a 2 character word + 3 character word? Answer:
>  $\frac{5!}{(5-2)!}$ + $\frac{5!}{(5-3)!}$
>  So the sigma just sums them up.

Then he said that it makes sense that the right formula is bigger than the wrong one (with factorial).

So I decided to check how much is it bigger (the ratio) so, I wrote in my calculator:

## $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{x=3}^8{\frac{8!}{(8-x)!}}}{8!}$ (n=8)

And got the result: *2.716666*
Immediately I thought of the golden ratio. So I checked bigger numbers seeing if I can get closer to *e*.
When n=15, the result is *2.718281828*

SO. my question: anyone has an explanation for that? It's really interesting as to why this happens.

Comment: Once you cancel out the $n!$ in the numerator and denominator, that just gives the sum of $\dfrac{1}{n!}$ in reverse, which is the series expansion for $e$: $e = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n!}$. (Here, you start from $n-3$ and go to $0$.)

Comment: Yes. Have you ever seen $e = 1+1+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+\dfrac{1}{4!}+\dots$? That's basically it, but you're starting from the end and going backward.

Comment: @KM101 How can you cancel the **n!** from the numerator if its a sigma? how does that work?

Comment: Every term has that factor, so you could factor it out. (It's a constant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally,

$\begin{array}\\
s(m, n)
&=\dfrac{\sum_{x=m}^n{\dfrac{n!}{(n-x)!}}}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{n!\sum_{x=m}^n{\dfrac{1}{(n-x)!}}}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{x=m}^n{\dfrac{1}{(n-x)!}}}{1}\\
&=\sum_{x=m}^n{\dfrac{1}{(n-x)!}}\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{n-m}{\dfrac{1}{x!}}\\
&\to\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{x!}}
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
&=e\\
\end{array}
$